# 8192 character limit for api on IIS + nginx server

Tags: .net, nginx, iis, hosting, handler

I am facing an issue intermittently.  I have a website hosted on IIS on server.
The project is on .Net and I use ashx handler to communicate with the API's.

From past two days I am facing a weird issue i.e. my every post api request which is exceeding the 8192 character limit is failing and giving 500 internal server error.

I have checked the web.config and every possible places but could not find the issue.

Comment: Have you viewed Failed request tracing log? First of all, we need to figure out this error is thrown from IIS pipeline or .NET runtime and what the detailed error message is. Besides,Have you tried to modify httpruntime/maxrequest length or serverruntime/uploadReadAheadSize.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below configuration :

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

For more deatils: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/